# What are the light and dark colors on the "distributions" page of tensorboard?

Tags: tensorboard

In the [tensorboard utility that comes with tensorflow 1.4](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.4/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) there is a DISTRIBUTIONS tab to the left of the HISTOGRAMS tab. When I look at a distribution, there is a light and dark color. Example:

[image: DISTRIBUTIONS graph]

What do the light and dark colors mean?  I'm pretty sure dark is the more common values (say, the middle n-th percentiles of the distribution), but I can't find docs on it.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, found [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard):

> Each line on the chart represents a percentile in the distribution
>   over the data: for example, the bottom line shows how the minimum
>   value has changed over time, and the line in the middle shows how the
>   median has changed. Reading from top to bottom, the lines have the
>   following meaning: [maximum, 93%, 84%, 69%, 50%, 31%, 16%, 7%,
>   minimum]
>
> These percentiles can also be viewed as standard deviation boundaries
>   on a normal distribution: [maximum, μ+1.5σ, μ+σ, μ+0.5σ, μ, μ-0.5σ,
>   μ-σ, μ-1.5σ, minimum] so that the colored regions, read from inside to
>   outside, have widths [σ, 2σ, 3σ] respectively.